# Pass generic into Implicit class

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I´m pretty newby on Scala, and I´m stack trying to pass a generic type into a implicit class, but I cannot find the way to do it.

Here my implicit class

```
object Utils{ 
  implicit class cacheUtils[T:ClassTag](cache:CacheApi){
    def getVal(key:String): T = cache.get(key).get
  }
}
```

And how I´m invoking

```
  import implicits.Utils.cacheUtils

  Test @Inject()(cache: CacheApi) extends Controller {

       val xxx: List[X] = cache.getVal(xx.asString) 
  }
```

But obviously he expect a type `T` and not the `List[X]`

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two problems in your code.

1. `CacheApi` should be parametric with type `T`, meaning, it should look like this: `class CacheApi[T](...)`, and your `cacheUtils` class parameter should be `cache: CacheApi[T]` instead of `cache: CacheApi`
2. Less important, but the context bound seems to be redundant here.

#### Edit

As per OP's request, here is a full example:

```
class CacheApi[T](list: List[T]) {
  def get = list.head
}

object Utils {
  implicit class cacheUtils[T](cache: CacheApi[T]) {
    def getVal(key: String): T = cache.get
  }
}

import Utils._

val cacheStrings = new CacheApi(List("hello"))
val cacheLists = new CacheApi(List(List(42)))

val s: String = cacheStrings.getVal("")
val list: List[Int] = cacheLists.getVal("")
```

Comment: The first option is not possible, at least with implicits. Could you please paste the code to take a look